# Calculate number of solutions

Tags: combinatorics

Count number of integral solutions of the equations $\sqrt{K-x^2} \geq 0$  where $x$ Is any variable and $K$ is any positive integer?(also the value of $\sqrt{K-x^2}$ should be an integer).

Answer (score 3):

The square root is defined on $\Bbb R_{0}^+$ and its value is non negative so the given inequality is equivalent to
$$k-x^2\ge0\iff x\in[-\sqrt k,\sqrt k]$$
so the number of integer solutions is
$$2\lfloor\sqrt k\rfloor+1$$

Comment: thanks for replying.But out of total solutions( i.e 2*sqrt(K) + 1)how many solutions will be there satisfying the condition that sqrt(K-x*x) will be an positive integer?

Comment: @typedef he already mentioned that.

Comment: @ADG I don't think he mentioned it.For example for K=7,as per his answer the possible values of x would be {-2,-1,0,1,2}.But after substituting the values in the equation I would obtain {sqrt(7),sqrt(3) and sqrt(6)} which is not an integer.But I want to obtain those solutions which would give an integral value when substituting back into an equation (i.e. sqrt(K-x*x) >=0).

Comment: oh he just mentioned about integral values of $x$, not $\sqrt{k-x^2}$. So i think this is wrong @typedef